# Denoise Node Not Working for Image Node

Tags: compositing-nodes, image, denoise

I am in a situation that I want to composite noisy renders, normal maps, and albedos rendered by someone else from Keyshot. Denoising in Keyshot is quite bugging therefore we are experimenting with this hybrid workflow. I have imported these components as Image Node however the denoise node is not doing anything to the image. I am using a generic 'noisy image' from the internet here as example to show my nodes. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I don't think this will work. When you render an image there is the denoise data generated (normal and albedo) that is required to denoise the image. You don't have this information for your example image.